# How to create download link to Azure File Storage documents? PDF works, but XLS and DOC dont

Tags: excel, azure, ms-access, file-storage

I have an Azure File Storage setup for a MS-Access application where users click on an SAS (shared access signature) link in a form to view documents on Azure File Storage. For PDF documents this works ok, the pdf opens up in Microsoft Edge, no issues. But for XLS and DOC files, the SAS link opens in Microsoft Edge as raw data.

Is there a way to get the link to prompt as a download rather than view in the browser?

Or can the XLS or DOC files be opened directly in the users default windows program rather than trying to open in a browser?

Not sure if there are settings that need to be changed in the Access form, or if its an Azure File Storage issue, as I couldn't see any obvious settings in either Azure or Access.

When I copy the SAS link into the browser, XLS and DOC files open as raw data

Example of what is shown in browser;

PK!`’z¾€ [Content_Types].xml ¢( ÄTÍJ1¾ ¾Ã’«ì¦ö "Ýzðç¨Bë¤Ét74›„ÌTÛ·w6Ú"R[Š/Y²É|?“äÝ®:W¼AB|-.«(Àë`¬ojñ:},¯E¤¼Q.x¨ÅPÜŽÏÏFÓu,¸Úc-Z¢x#%ê:…UˆàyeR§ˆ§©‘Qé…j@ƒ+©ƒ'ðTR!Æ£{˜«¥£âaÅ¿?•Ì¬ÅÝç¾žª*Fgµ"*ß¼ùAR†ùÜj0A/;†®0&P[ê\“eÆ4"6†BîäLàð8Ò/WWfaØÚˆlý†~åwW_uÏ|É(^T¢'Õ±w¹rò=¤Å,„EµäØÖäU²~£{ÞŒ2.O,¤÷—Ô1ü'ÄwdÿÞŠ sÀ8ÒÚžúø3è!æV%0âWÔœ\Àwì:´rú®å«zâ&lq÷ñs´¼¤‘Ó+Áñ6QÑW—‘ ‘…

If a Blob storage is more suited to what I want, let me know, this section of the application is being developed so no problem having to moving things around to get a better outcome in the long run.

Again, PDF files no issue, XLS and DOC file types are the problem.

Comment: You can try use blob storage, I just have a test, it will prompt to download.

Comment: Please check the content type property of the file which are giving you the problem.

Comment: I tested it and can download it. and can read the content of the excel file. Check the permissions

Comment: its all XLS and DOC files giving the problem.

Comment: i'll try a blob storage and report back what happens

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure storage explore I tried with following permissions and works for me

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work either. I use Storage Explorer already, and changing permissions still produced the same result. XLS and DOC files try to open in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help guys, I put the XLS and DOC files on Blob storage and it works a treat. Not sure the differences between File Share and Blob Storage, but Blob Storage does exactly what I want. Will be moving all the files to the Blob storage.